# ¿cómo puedo renombrar una cadena basada en otra cadena que tenga un prefijo diferente?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, csv

Tengo una spreadsheet de google que he almacenado con el nombre que quiero usar, el origen, en las primeras filas y los nombres que quiero cambiar en la primera columna, el destino (de la línea 2).

```
#1 - Giorgi Margvelashvili  #1 - Mikheil Saakashvili    #1 - United National Movement   #10 - Levan Chachua #10 - National Party of Radical Democrats of Georgia    #10 - People's Party    #11 - Akaki Asatiani    #11 - Giorgi Chikhladze
Giorgi Margvelashvili   Georgian Dream                      
Mikheil Saakashvili United National Movement                        
United National Movement    United National Movement                        
Nino Chanishvili    Initiative Group
```

En la medida en que el objetivo es similar pero todavía un poco diferente (`#number - mismoNombreQueElObjetivo`), ¿cómo puedo renombrar una cadena basada en otra cadena que tenga un prefijo diferente?

Intente esto en javascript (pero una respuesta en Python está bien para mí también) pero sólo pasamos la prueba si la fuente y el objetivo son exactamente iguales.

```
/**
This function will rename the cells of the first columns if they have an elment of the first row 
@customFunction
*/
function RENAMECELL() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  for(var i = 1; i<60; i++){
    // if the name is in the first row
    for(var j = 1;j<50){      
      if(name == activeSheet.getRange(j,1).getValue()){
        activeSheet.getRange(i,1).setValue(name == activeSheet.getRange(j,1).getValue());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Advertencia, algunas funciones.includes() no parecen estar implementadas en el editor de scripts de google

```
/**
This function will rename the cells of the first columns if they have an elment of the first row 
@customFunction
*/
function RENAMECELL() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  for (var row = 2; row < 60; row++) {
    var name = activeSheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
    console.log(name);
    for (var col = 1; col < 50; col++) {
      if (activeSheet.getRange(1,col).getValue().indexOf(name) !== -1) {
        activeSheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(activeSheet.getRange(1,col).getValue());
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```